# machine learning algorithm for e-mail classification

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

[image: Ham Vs Spam email algorithm]

I'm reading the following book http://alex.smola.org/drafts/thebook.pdf and on page 22 (what's shown in the image) it talks about a simple test which clasifies an e-mail as ham or spam.

I'm unsure exactly what by $x$ and $y$ refer to, when they say

"In the example of the AIDS test we used the outcomes of the test to infer
whether the patient is diseased. In the context of spam filtering the actual
text of the e-mail $x$ corresponds to the test and the label $y$ is equivalent to
the diagnosis. Recall Bayes Rule (1.15)."

What i'm confused about is whether $x$ is assigned 'ham' or 'spam' based on whether the e-mail is or is not and $y$ is assigned 'true (test diagnoses it as spam)' or 'false' as the diagnosis of the test, or whether it's the other way around and $y$ is assigned 'ham' or 'spam' and $x$ is 'true' or 'false'.

In the example of they refer to, this was clear $X$ was the random variable which was assigned a value of AIDS or no AIDS and $T$ was the random variable which represented the outcome of a test positive or negative.

I'd be grateful if someone could help clear this issue up in this instance and in addition clarify exactly what they mean by $\mathbb{P}(x|y).$

Answer (score 0):

$y=\{smap,ham\}$ is the variable that denotes the (real, not observed, to be guessed) "state". $x$ is the feature vector (observation, mail content in this case).

What we want to compute (in any classification problem) is $p(y \mid x)$ : probability that the mail is (or not) spam, given the observation.

> What i'm confused about is whether $x$ is assigned 'ham' or 'spam' based on whether the e-mail is or is not and $y$ is assigned 'true (test diagnoses it as spam)' or 'false' as the diagnosis of the test, or whether it's the other way around and $y$ is assigned 'ham' or 'spam' and $x$ is 'true' or 'false'.

I don't quite get why you say that the variable "is assigned" this or that value. The computation of all the probabilities are only that: probabilities, they are previous to the classification (guess, labelling). The value of $y$ depends on whether the mail is *actually* spam or not. The value of $x$ depends on the feature (some measurement, perhaps multimensional, on the observed mail).

Comment: Ok so you say the value of $x$ depends on whether the mail is actually spam or not can you elaborate on this? The way i've been viewing it is $x$ represents whether the e-mail is truly spam or not and $y$ represents whether the algorithm classifies it as spam or not, i guess this interpretation is not correct? In addition in the text it states that $p(y)$ represents the probability that the e-mail is actually spam, not the probability it is classified as spam as you stated, that's also something else which is confusing me.

Comment: "$y$ represents whether the algorithm classifies it as spam..." No, that's wrong. It that were the case, it wouldn't make sense to speak of the probability $p(y|x)$ because the classification is deterministic.

Comment: "not the probability it is classified as spam as you stated" I didn't state that.  - though I messed up the letters in the last paragraph. Fixed.

Comment: Ahh that makes more sense now thanks

Comment: So just to clarify $P(y|x)$ represents the probability $y$ is spam given some feature vector of an e-mail $x$. Hypothetically we could have some set of text corresponding to $x$ and in one e-mail it could be spam and in another ham so really $P(y|x)$ will probably depend on exactly what is contained in the text. Is this on the right lines?

Comment: Yes... though I would avoid saying that a probability "probably" depends on something :-)